# Rule of Sample Proporitions - What is the minimum sample size for a 2 Proportion Z Test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, assumptions

I've been reading different resources, and I've been confused over the requirements for the minimum sample sizes to perform a 2 Proportion Z-Test.

I'll be listing the rule, and the corresponding website(s) I found it on.

**1) Minimum of 5 successes & 5 failures**

Sources: [PDF File 1](http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/100/fall2012/lectures/lectureNotes/lecture28Nov7.pdf)

**2) np≥10 and n(1−p)≥10**

Source: [PSU Link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/book/export/html/144)

^ So I am confused which rule is "correct," as well as the derivation for those rules. I want to understand HOW those rules were derived in the first place. Any insights would be helpful!

Comment: Your links seem to point to descriptions of one-sample proportions. Is your question about one-sample analyses or about distinguishing proportion differences between 2 samples?

Comment: @EdM - It's for distinguishing proportion differences between 2 (or more) samples.

Comment: The minimum sample size depends very much on your desired $\alpha$ (type I error rate), $\delta = |p_{1} - p_{2}|$ (desired minimum relevant effect size), and $1 - \beta$ (desired statistical power).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues here. The "requirements" you list are for a different issue than for comparing 2 groups. They refer to when a normal distribution is close enough to the distribution of successes in binomial sampling to allow a Z-test, which assumes a normal distribution. Binomial sampling only leads to integer numbers of successes, while the normal distribution is continuous. So a normal distribution can't be exactly equivalent to a binomial. With enough cases, however, you can use a [normal approximation to the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation). The 2 requirements you cite are among several rules of thumb for when a normal distribution is "close enough" to a binomial; as the Wikipedia page puts it: "the specific number varies from source to source, and depends on how good an approximation one wants."

The second issue is what sample sizes are needed to compare proportions in two or more samples. That involves additional considerations: What are the expected probabilities of successes in the two groups? What is your criterion for a "significant difference" between the 2 groups (*p*-value)? How certain do you want to be that you will not miss a true difference between the groups simply due to random sampling (power)?

In many cases you will need more than 5 or 10 successes in each group to distinguish a difference between them. A web search for something like "two sample proportion test power calculator" will link to online tools that perform the necessary calculations. For example, [this page](http://statulator.com/SampleSize/ss2P.html#) says that to distinguish a group having a 20% success rate from one having a 35% success rate you would need 149 in each group to provide 80% power at a two-sided *p*-value of 0.05. You'll note that the numbers of successes expected are well above those needed for a reasonable normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: The problem is that with those calculators, is that you'll need to know the proportions in advance. I don't know that information in advance.

Also, in the case where events are very rare, like .01%; I can have samples where sample A shows: 2/500, and sample B shows 0/500, out of "luck," and I believe it'll show sample A as significant just because of "bad luck." I thought that was the rationale for having a minimum number of success and failures. I just want to be able to justify the value 5, or whatever value...

Comment: @Shazbots that is the problem with _all_ attempts to estimate the sample size needed for a study. You always need estimates of both the difference that you think exists and the variance of that difference. For rare events you can use the [Poisson approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Poisson_approximation) to the binomial, for which the variance estimate can equal the number of (rare) successes. But even then you have to know how big a difference you expect between your 2 groups to determine how many cases you need in each group to detect a difference.

Comment: There are multiple rules of thumb for both one sample and two sample proportion tests (more than the ones you mention).

None are "correct"; all rely on pretty much completely arbitrary judgements about what's "close enough". Usually they're not really "derived" in a strict mathematical sense. While some can be based on meeting some specific criterion or other, typically they are not, and even when they are, that usually doesn't mean you're really getting what you're actually seeking (a close enough approximation of some p-value, power, sample size or whatever, for your purposes).  
... ctd

Comment: ctd... No rule is really quite satisfactory in every situation. You're better off figuring out what properties you need in a particular case and seeing what it takes to get them (or even just avoiding the normal approximation altogether in some situations).